# GeoFire Query Callback Not Firing

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, geofire

I am trying to implement `geofire` into one of my `firebase` cloud functions and can't understand why the query callbacks are not firing. The dashboard log continues to display nothing returned or nothing documented via `console.log()`.

Any guidance would be appreciated..below is my code:

```
exports.test = functions.firestore.document('/x/{userId}').onWrite((change, context) => {
const userData = change.after.exists ? change.after.data() : null;
const geoPoint = userData.location;
const lat = geoPoint._latitude;
const long = geoPoint._longitude;

var geoFireRef = firebase.database().ref('geoLocations');
var geoFire = new GeoFire(geoFireRef);

const circle = geoFire.query({
  center: [lat, long],
  radius: 0.5
});

circle.on('key_entered', function(key, location, distance) {
  console.log(key + " entered query at " + location + " (" + distance + " km from center)");
  return;
});

circle.on('ready', function() {
  console.log('ready');
  return;
});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was nothing wrong with the code. I figured out the issue was found with the set rules that prevented the geofire query from executing in the first place.